# Limit each firebase user to only one auth provider?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

How do I make it so that when a new user signs up in firebase, they can only login with that provider? Ex: a new user uses an email and password to sign up and then is rejected when trying to log in with Google.

I'm using Firebase with javascript in React if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're asking doesn't sound possible.  The different auth providers don't know about each others' user bases.  jackoboy on Google isn't at all related to jackoboy on Facebook.  While they might have the same email address, that's never a guarantee that they are the same individual.  So when jackoboy signs up with Google, there is nothing that can possibly stop jackoboy from also signing up with Facebook as a different account.

If you want to impose your own checks to see if the end user might be the same, you're going to have to write some code for that on a backend you control, then delete the second account if it appears to be the same person, by whatever logic you determine.  Firebase Auth just isn't going to do that for you.